# Separando um dataframe por algum criterio python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ipython-notebook

Eu tenho uma base de dados que possui 789 avaliações de pessoas sobre um determinado produto, ela possui as colunas comentários e estrelas. Eu normalizei os dados para positivos (estrela >= 3) 1 e negativos 0.

```
outputs = data_frame['estrelas']

rotulo = list()

for output in outputs:
  if output >= 3:
    rotulo.append(1)
  else:
    rotulo.append(0)
```

Depois contei o número de positivos e negativos do dataset e veio que possui 738 positivos e 51 negativos. O que eu preciso é que eles fiquem igualados sendo 51 negativos e 51 positivos,ou seja, ao todo 102 registros. Estou utilizando python e pandas.

Comment: Não sei se entendi o problema. O DataFrame possui 789 linhas, das quais 738 possuem a coluna `estrela` com valor >=3 e 51 com valor <3. O objetivo é pegar, desses 738, apenas 51? Tem algum critério para escolher estes 51?

Comment: Isso mesmo! Não, ele só precisa ser >= 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira é pegar o index das linhas positivas, selecionar apenas 51 valores, juntar com os index das linhas negativas e manter apenas as linhas selecionadas:

```
# Pego os ids das linhas com estrelas positovas e negativas
ids_positivos = df[df['estrelas'] >= 3].index.values
ids_negativos = df[df['estrelas'] < 3].index.values

# Opcionalmente posso embaralhar os ids para pegar linhas aleatórias
#numpy.random.shuffle(ids_positivos)

# Seleciono os primeiros 51 valores
ids_positivos = ids_positivos[:51]
ids_negativos = ids_negativos[:51] # No caso seleciono todos os negativos

# Concateno todos os ids em um array só
ids_para_manter = numpy.concatenate((ids_positivos, ids_negativos))

# Crio um novo DataFrame com os ids selecionados
novo_df = df.iloc[ids_para_manter]
```

De maneira enxuta temos:

```
ids_positivos = df[df['estrelas'] >= 3].index.values[:51]
#ids_positivos = numpy.random.shuffle(df[df['estrelas'] >= 3].index.values)[:51]
ids_negativos = df[df['estrelas'] < 3].index.values[:51]


novo_df = df.iloc[numpy.concatenate((ids_positivos, ids_negativos))].reset_index()
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! Era isso mesmo